# how to fetch files from RestApi flutter

Tags: flutter, image, api, rest, file

I'm trying to get Image file from Rest Api to show it in **CircleAvatar**
Here's the photo of the Api
[image: Image from API]

and I used Future for this:

```
  Future<Int8List> getProfileImg() async {
final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
final String? accessToken = prefs.getString('accessToken');
print(accessToken);
final response = await http.get(
  Uri.parse(RestClient.getProfileImage),
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': ' Bearer $accessToken',
  },
);

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  final ByteData data =
  await NetworkAssetBundle(Uri.parse(response.body)).load(response.body);
  final Int8List bytes = data.buffer.asInt8List();
  return bytes;
  // return User.fromJson(json.decode(response.body.toString()));
} else {
  print(response.statusCode);
  throw Exception('Failed to get profile image');
}
```

}

Then when I want to print **print(response.bodyBytes);**
it shown like:

```
[137, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10, 0, 0, 0, 13, 73, 72, 68, 82, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 8, 2, 0, 0, 0, 151, 134, 104, 160, 0, 0, 140, 176, 73, 68, 65, 84, 120, 218, 236, 221, 137, 82, 91, 215, 158, 232, 225, 251, 254, 207, 17, 16, 2, 73, 123, 107, 107, 96, 30, 13, 216, 198, 54, 96, 131, 153, 12, 24, 11, 52, 236, 17, 231, 13, 110, 9, 146, 147, 56, 113, 218, 118, 226, 1, 201, 95, 213, 87, 167, 250, 118, 165, 115, 186, 221, 105, 237, 245, 187, 107, 173, 255, 250, 127, 55, 189, 62, 0, 0, 0, 140, 189, 255, 231, 143, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 12, 0, 0, 0, 2, 24, 0, 0, 0, 4, 48, 0, 0, 0, 8, 96, 0, 0, 0, 16, 192, 0, 0, 0, 32, 128, 1, 0, 0, 64, 0, 3, 0, 0, 128, 0, 6, 0, 0, 64, 0, 3, 0, 0, 128, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 1, 12, 0, 0, 0, 2, 24, 0, 0, 0, 4, 48, 0, 0, 0, 8, 96, 0, 0, 0, 16, 192, 0, 0, 0, 32, 128, 1, 0, 0, 64, 0, 3, 0, 0, 32, 128, 1, 0, 0, 64, 0, 3, 0, 0, 128, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 1, 12, 0, 0, 0, 2, 24, 0, 0, 0, 4, 48, 0, 0, 0, 8, 96, 0, 0, 0, 16, 192, 0, 0, 0, 32, 128, 1, 0, 0, 16, 192, 0, 0, 0, 32, 128, 1, 0, 0, 64, 0, 3, 0, 0, 128,
```

after that I want to use it in the CircleAvatar as:

```
  Widget buildProfileImage() => CircleAvatar(
radius: profileHeight / 2,
backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade800,
child: Image.memory(_user),
// backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
  // _user.asStream(),
  // 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_960_720.png',
// ),
```

);

but the problem here is I can't use Image.memory or byteStream.

Answer (score 0):

use it in the backgroundImage

```
CircleAvatar(
          backgroundImage: MemoryImage(decoded),
        ),
```

if it work, arrow up,

Comment: That what I tried to do in the code, but it didn't work

Comment: try it with same content, your way is a little different, I do it in my work and it's work